# How can I join two conditional subqueries in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I'm trying to join two subqueries in PGAdmin (v1.20.0), as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        course_code "400-Level Courses", 
        meet_time_start "Starting Time", 
        meet_time_end "End Time", 
        meet_day_of_week "Day", 
        building_code "Building", 
        building_room_no "Room" 
    FROM faculty_course_credit
    LEFT JOIN course_schedule USING (term_id, course_code, course_ref_no)
    WHERE (SUBSTRING(course_code, 4, 1) = '4') AND meet_time_start != '00:00'
) 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            course_code "500-Level Courses", 
            meet_time_start "Starting Time", 
            meet_time_end "End Time", 
            meet_day_of_week "Day", 
            building_code "Building", 
            building_room_no "Room" 
        FROM faculty_course_credit 
        LEFT JOIN course_schedule USING (term_id, course_code, course_ref_no)
        WHERE (SUBSTRING(course_code, 4, 1) = '5') AND meet_time_start != '00:00'
    )
) 
USING (
    building_code=building_code, 
    building_room_no=building_room_no, 
    meet_time_start=meet_time_start, 
    meet_time_end=meet_time_end, 
    meet_day_of_week=meet_day_of_week
)
```

I don't have permission to create tables in the schema, and I keep getting the following error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
> LINE 1:  select * from (
>                        ^
> HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
> SQL state: 42601
> Hint: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
> Character: 16
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error says it all. Every subquery or derived table **must** have an alias. It looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( ... ) AS alias1 -- AS keyword is not needed, but I prefer it for readability
```

This is the part you're missing.

---

Also, if you have similar names in both derived tables you are joining, and you are using the `JOIN ... USING ()` syntax, then the proper way to do that would be:

```
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2 -- this is to show you that names in both tables are identical
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 USING (col1, col2)
```

Meaning that you don't need equality operators for this. You only specify equality conditions when using the `JOIN ... ON` clause, which in the case above would look like:

```
SELECT t.*, t2.*
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t.col1 = t2.col1 AND t.col2 = t2.col2
```

---

I've noticed that you are renaming your columns in both derived tables. In the JOIN clause you need to specify names that are available to the outer query. Those would be the renamed column names, not their initial names.